# How can you pass URL Parameters at URL slashed address? (www.example.com/1/2 = www.example.com?x=1&y=2)

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I want to be able to take a url and map it to a set of web parameters. For example:

www.example.com/1/2/3 would be interpreted as www.example.com/default.asp?x=1&y=2&z=3

I know I've seen it done, I just can't find it anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite

Answer (score 0):

With CGI, look for the `PATH_INFO` environment variable. Note that when you're handling an image map, the coordinates of a click are always sent via the `QUERY_STRING` (or the POSTed equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

This may require asp.net.  One solution is to handle all your requests in the global.asax.  Generally using URL rewriting is better than this (it's already written and designed to do this), though this gives you more control.  This may also require the use of a 404 redirector in order to ensure that the urls are routed to asp.